# Nested array inside variable in for loop

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm beginning in Bash and I try to do this, but I can't.

Example:

```
array=("/dev/sda1" "/dev/sdb1")

for i in "${array[@]";do
    space=$(df -H | grep ${array[1]})
done
```

or this:

```
i=0

for i in ("/dev/sda1" "/dev/sdb1")
    space=$(df -h | grep (($i++)))
done
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly feed the array into `df` like below and avoid using `for-loop` like

```
df -H "${array[@]}"
```

However, if this is a venture to study the `for-loop` in bash then  you can do the same like below

```
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
 df -H "$i" 
 # Well, "${array[@]}" expands to everything in array
 # and i takes each value in each turn.
done
```

And if you wish to access the array using index, then

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)) # This is a c-style for loop
do 
  df -H "${array[i]}" # Note the index i is not prefixed with $
done
```

**Edit**

To check if the usage is more than, say, 10GB

```
# We will usage file which we would use to fill the body of mail
# This file will contain the file system usage
# But first make sure the file is empty before every run
cat /dev/null > /tmp/diskusagereport
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
 usage=$(df -H "$i" | awk 'END{sub(/G$/,"",$3);print $3}')
 if [ "${usage:-0}" -gt 10 ]
 then
  echo "Filesystem : ${i} usage : ${usage}GB is greater than 10GB" >> /tmp/diskusagereport
 fi
done
#finally use the `mailx` client like below

mailx -v -r "from@address.in" -s "Disk usage report" \
      -S smtp="smtp.yourserver.org:port" -S smtp-auth=login \
      -S smtp-auth-user="your_auth_user_here" \
      -S smtp-auth-password='your_auth_password' \
                         to@address.com </tmp/diskusagereport
```

Comment: Might as well round out the exercise with `for ((i = 0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++)); do df -H "${array[i]}"; done` ... `:)`

Comment: Ok but how did the df result to a variable? The idea is to save the result in a variable to be able to execute an if

Comment: @Ceac  May I know what are you planning to do with the variable? Often you will need a specific value from `df` to do some computations based on it.

Comment: I need to compare it to run a script and trigger an email

Comment: @Ceac : compare what? Are you looking to extract a particular field from `df` For example check the free space is less than `30%` or so?

Comment: Yes, I need to do what you say

Comment: @Ceac : See my edit and do accept the answer if it helped.